# .htaccess redirect all nonexistant directories to file

Tags: .htaccess

I am attempting to redirect all non-existent directories to a single file.

Examples:
/test = category.php?cat=test
/category = category.php?cat=category

The following code works in the parent directory but it is not working when someone is directed into a sub-directory that exists.  I have a folder /clients that requires a login.  If someone tries access that folder and they are not logged in it is coded to send them to login.php.  However it is sending them to category.php?cat=clients. Im assuming this is a confusing between two forwarders but I am unable to determine the repair.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/? category.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude existing directories manually by adding this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(contact|news|blog)
```